# Python turtle Game

Tags: python

```
import turtle
s1 = turtle.Screen()
b = turtle.Turtle()
b.shape("turtle")
b.color("blue")
b.speed(9)
s1.bgpic("grass.gif")


########## turtles
t1 = turtle.Turtle()
t1.shape('circle')
t1.pu()
t1.goto(100,200)

t2 = turtle.Turtle()
t2.shape('circle')
t2.pu()
t2.goto(-100,-200)

t3 = turtle.Turtle()
t3.shape('circle')
t3.pu()
t3.goto(200,-200)

t3 = turtle.Turtle()
t3.shape('circle')
t3.pu()
t3.goto(-300,100)

t4 = turtle.Turtle()
t4.shape('circle')
t4.pu()
t4.goto(0,200)

t5 = turtle.Turtle()
t5.shape('circle')
t5.pu()
t5.goto(400,300)
###################################################3

score = 0
def eat():
    if  t1.pos() == b.pos():
        t1.hideturtle()
        print("You found  peice of food!")
        score
        score += 1
        return("Your score is", score)



    elif t2.pos() == b.pos():
        t2.hideturtle()
    print("You found  peice of food!")
    score
    score += 1
    return("Your score is", score)


elif t3.pos() == b.pos():
    t3.hideturtle()
    print("You found  peice of food!")
    score
    score += 1
    return("Your score is", score)

elif t4.pos() == b.pos():
    t4.hideturtle()
    print("You found  peice of food!")
    score
    score += 1
    return("Your score is", score)

elif t5.pos() == b.pos():
    t5.hideturtle()
    print("You found  peice of food!")
    score
    score += 1
    return("Your score is", score)
```

My directions are to
Draw a background containing several turtles, each with a shape resembling an item of food.

When the player moves his main turtle to one of these food turtles, and types in eat() at the idle prompt, the eat() function checks to see if the player's turtle is near any of the food turtles, and if it is, it makes that food turtle disappear. It also increments a displayed score counter which keeps track of how many items the player's turtle has eaten.

How do I make it so my turtle eats the other turtles with my eat() function when it is near the other turtles, not only when it is on the exact same position?

Comment: What do you mean "close"? Like, I know what you mean, but forcing yourself to explain it in detail might make it *click* how you can write that explanation into your Python test code...  (hint: .goto(100,200) - how would you decide in your head if (100,150) is "close" to that or not? (800,200)? (800,-200)?)

Comment: Both coordinates of the turtle within 25 units of the other turtle.  I'm confused about how to put > and < for both coordinates into my code.

Comment: `if 5 < 6 and 10 > 2:` Look at the `abs()` function as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use abs function, but first you need to unpack the tuple, because t.pos() is function that returns a **tuple (x, y)**. After you assign conponents of this tuple to new variables you can easily see how near are they using abs() function.

You can read more about abs() here: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_abs.asp

And here is explained how to unpack the tuple: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/unpacking-a-tuple-in-python/

I hope I helped you, and good luck with your game.

Comment: I just realized I am 5 years late.